# Reading large text file in chunks Processing

Tags: java, performance, processing

I have a very large text file (about 8.5 million lines, 1 GB) that is made up of geographical info (the Geoname Project, for anyone who's heard of it). Currently I'm using BufferedReader and have found that my program can comfortably read 10000 lines and display some required data without much pause. However, I have to read and search each line in the whole file, and as soon as I test it with more than 50000 lines the program becomes very slow and basically useless. What are some options for dividing up the file and reading it in chunks, thus reducing execution time?

Comment: Why would you think that dividing up the file would help, if you still need to go through every line? `BufferedReader` already does "chunking" (hence the name `Buffered`), so if anything, dividing the file would be *slower* as you'd have to operate on several files instead of a single one.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file

Comment: I agree with what Kayaman said. `BufferedReader` already reads in chunks. It sounds like you're hitting a memory problem. Have you tried simply increasing the amount of memory available? If that doesn't work, please post a [mcve] so we can see exactly what's happening.

Comment: @KevinWorkman how does one go about increasing the memory?

Comment: @galaxyphoenix67 I'm surprised that googling something like "Processing sketch increase memory" didn't return any results for you. But you can access this setting in File > Preferences.

Answer (score -1):

Read about java.nio.Buffer class and its sub-classes. Especially pay attention to dirrect and non-direct buffers and pros and cons of their usages. Direct buffers provide direct access to disk and ability to process very large files in chunks and very fast. But this great ability comes with some price and risk of memory leaks. But I think that is what you may need. Start reading here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html